# Inserting Data in Object with Hard Coded Form in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two tables `Product` & `Orders`, What I did was, I created `View` and and Hard Coded HTML form that passes the `Ordered Products` into `Order` Object.
While saving the `Orders` I am getting error `INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint`
I have added the breakpoints as well, all values are being properly filled in Orders Object, but  `Id` & `Products` property is null.

I have created a One to Many Relationship as seen in image below.
[image: Relationship one to many between orders and products]

**This is my view**

```
@model Myapp.Areas.Admin.ViewModel.ProductDisplayViewModel
@ViewBag.Message    
    @using (Html.BeginForm("OrderProduct", "Order"))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Your Name</label>           
            <input id="Name" name="Name" class="form-control" type="text"/>
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
        <label>Your Email</label>
        @Html.TextBox("Email", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Your Contact Number</label>
        @Html.TextBox("ContactNumber", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Your Address</label>
        @Html.TextBox("Address", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Quantity</label>
        @Html.TextBox("Quantity", null, new { @class = "form-control",type="Number" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Any Comments</label>
        @Html.TextBox("Comments", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.Hidden("ProductId", Model.ProductId)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Order Now" class="read-more"/>        
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index")" class="read-more">Back to Products</a>

    </div>
        }
```

**This is my Action Method in Orders Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult OrderProduct(Orders order)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Orders.Add(order);
        db.SaveChanges();
        // if Order Saved in DB show success Message and Redirect on the same product page
        ViewBag.Message = "Value Entered in DB";
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Product", new { id = order.ProductId });
    }
    // if something went wrong Redirect on the same product page
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Product", new { id = order.ProductId });
}
```

Comment: Its a bit hard to understand what the issue is. Your view does not contain an input for `Id` so it will always be `0` (assuming its typeof `int`). But you are creating an input for `ProductId` so assuming you have set a value for it in the GET method, you will get it in the POST method. But why are you manually creating html such as `<input id="Name" name="Name" class="form-control" type="text"/>` instead of `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new  { @class = "form-control" })` and creating `<label>` elements that are not labels (it should be `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)`

Comment: And then why do you redirect if `ModelState` is not valid? - it should be `return View(order);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke basically I posted a part of the view, What my view actually does is, it contains a model of Product and in it, I am rendering a HTML form to order that product, and I am again redirecting to that page because I want to show a error or success message. And my form do have an hidden field of ProductId which is going from POST request with the rest of the data

Comment: Yes I know you have a control for Product Id - that's what I stated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProductId should be the Id from the products table, going by your definition but you're passing Model.ProductId which would cause your issue.

Populate the ProductId field of the model you're returning with the Product.Id from the product your adding the order for.

```
newOrderObject.ProductId = Product.Id
return View(newOrderObject);
```